# Using reflections to access methods in Amazon Deequ

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect, amazon-deequ

I plan on creating a user config file that I will later parse in order to run some checks from Amazon Deequ. I want to be able to pass the string names from the config file to get the methods; however, in my attempts to do so, I keep hitting roadblocks.

```
import com.amazon.deequ.checks._

val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val myClass = new Check(CheckLevel.Error, "unit testing my data")
val im = rm.reflect(myClass)

val methodSymbolNonNeg = ru.typeOf[Check].decl(ru.TermName("isNonNegative")).asMethod
val methodNonNeg = im.reflectMethod(methodSymbolNonNeg)

Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:48: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ru.MethodSymbol
 required: ru.MethodSymbol
       val methodNonNeg = im.reflectMethod(methodSymbolNonNeg)
```

I have tried a couple of examples from the documentation as well what I have found on here on SO. I have also checked the method names in the class `myClass.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).foreach{println}` as well as on Github.

Additionally, I have tried using `.getClass.getMethod` and invoking the method as well

```
val m = myClass.getClass.getMethod("isNonNegative", "".getClass, 2.13.getClass, Option("").getClass)

Name: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
Message: com.amazon.deequ.checks.Check.isNonNegative(java.lang.String, double, scala.Some)
StackTrace:   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
```

Comment: Do you really need to call any arbitrary method in runtime? Why not just mapping some names into some method at compile time using a match or a map?

Comment: BEWARE: [Json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce the compile error in your Scala reflection code.
With Scala 2.13.3 + Deequ 1.0.5 and Scala 2.11.12 + Deequ 1.0.5 your code compiles.
Write your versions of dependencies and Scala. Try **clean** rebuild of your project (e.g. `sbt clean compile` if you build your project with sbt).

Deequ 1.0.5 depends on versions of Scala libraries (Shapeless, Twitter Chill, Spark, json4s, scala-parser-combinators, scala-xml, Breeze, Spire, Machinist) for Scala 2.**11**.x so you should use Scala 2.**11**.x.

With Scala 2.13 I have `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable`.

Also notice that at https://github.com/awslabs/deequ it's written

> Deequ depends on Java 8 and is known to work with Apache Spark versions 2.2.x to 2.4.x.

Your compile error  `found: ru.MethodSymbol, required: ru.MethodSymbol` looks like some issue with versions of dependencies.

Regarding your Java reflection code you just specified incorrectly classes of method parameters. The signature of `Check#isNonNegative` is

```
def isNonNegative(
  column: String,
  assertion: Double => Boolean,
  hint: Option[String])
: CheckWithLastConstraintFilterable
```

so you should do

```
myClass.getClass.getMethod("isNonNegative", classOf[String], classOf[Double => Boolean], classOf[Option[_]])
```

By the way, mixing Scala reflection and Java reflection is weird.

Comment: Thanks I will have this looked into. This is corporate cluster so I need to have operations investigate before we will know.